# Setting default content of container when page loads/refresh then changes after click event fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to set default content of a container when page loads/refresh, so that it does not look empty until click event that populates the container is fired.

The jQuery i'm working with looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[class^="question"]').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var numb = this.className.replace('question', '');
$('[id^="answer"]').hide();
$('#answer' + numb).show();
});

});
```

My html makeup looks like this :

```
<div class="new_member_box">
     <a href="#" class="question1"><h4>Vision</h4></a>
</div> 

<div class="new_member_box_display" id="answer1">
    1
</div> 

  <div class="new_member_box_display" id="answer">
    Default
</div>
```

When The page loads, Default text is shown, but when I clicked  Vision link, 1 is shown then Default is shown in a box below it. What i want is that Default shows when page loads/refresh, then when a link is clicked default disappears and then the value for the clicked links is shown.

Comment: Your code should be working, can you please show a demo?

Comment: @Starx   [A live Demo here](http://goo.gl/79BaO)

When I click one of the links two boxes appears.

Answer (score 1):

Also include `$('[id^="answer"]').hide();` on dom ready..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('[id^=answer]').not('#answer').hide(); //add this
    //click function code

});
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWcAF/)

Answer (score 1):

Lets break down your code:

```
$('[id^="answer"]').hide(); //This hids all the elements starting with answer as id

$('#answer' + numb).show(); // and show a particular answer
```

But the default content box in your demo has `question` as an id

```
<div id="question" class="new_member_box_display">
    Text will appear here when one of the tabs above is clicked
</div>
```

So your script will not effect this part. A valid solution would be to add a class to represent this div as a default box. Something like

```
<div id="question" class="new_member_box_display default">
                                          <!--    ^ I added a class here -->
    Text will appear here when one of the tabs above is clicked
</div>
```

Then, in our script we will hide that first.

```
$(function() {
    $('[class^="question"]').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var numb = this.className.replace('question', '');
        $('.default').hide(); // Lets hide that first
        $('[id^="answer"]').hide();
        $('#answer' + numb).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. When I click the link, the corresponding text does not show and the page jumps to the top.

Comment: Default text should show first, then when any link is clicked the default text disappears and the text for the clicked link is displayed.

Comment: @Olubunmi, You have removed the `$(document).ready()` Place that like before